# Does anyone know how to make AutoCrat work with the correct number format?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, number-formatting

I'm trying to automate the creation of a monthly report, which have some financial information like "R$ 5.000,00". However, AutoCrat insert this information as "5000", losing all the number format.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: As you'll see from the comments beneath my answer (did you see that?), your question isn't clear. You could improve it immensely, and thereby help get better answers, by adding some more information. How are you creating your report? If by script, please include a minimal version of it that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you have questions or feature requests that are specific to the Autocrat Script, visit [the author's page](http://www.youpd.org/autocrat).

When a script reads a numeric value from a spreadsheet, it gets only the value. It is possible to also retrieve the format as a separate operation, but it appears that Autocrat is not doing that.

As a work-around, you could format that information as a string, rather than a number. The `TEXT()` function will do this for you:

```
=TEXT(--cell--,"R$ #,##0.00")
```

The screenshot below shows that the formatted text in B2 looks the same as the numeric value in A2, except for the horizontal alignment. If we then had Autocrat use the values in column B, the formatting would be preserved.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is not really practical as a way out, if you try to use the number afterwards to weight the grades of the students.

Comment: @vinnief - sounds like you have a different question that was originally asked... you could post it as a question. OR, follow up with Autocrat support.

Comment: Nope, Autocrat loses the format. (in my case in google sheet output) this is both my and the OP's problem. Your solution is a visual way out. But as for having the number as number and having a good format, that is not solved yet. Indeed we probably should take it up with the  Autocrat support in case it is not possible.